# Same Algorithm works very slow in windows and very fast in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, algorithm, opencv, ubuntu-12.04, mat

I have a same algorithm working in two computer. One with Ubuntu and other with windows.

- In Ubuntu, the algorithm takes a input images through a framework called **ADTF**. Here the algorithm works in **70fps**. Everything is perfect.
- In windows, the algorithm takes input images from a video stream without using any framework (visual studio 2012 as an IDE). Here the algorithm works in **2fps**.

When I checked for the computation time, I see a function in my algorithm which takes 0.4seconds in windows and 0.011seconds in Ubuntu. And this function has been called 'n' number of times in the process. This function uses only `cv::Mat` in its argument and some float. I don't think so the data type float is responsible for this big time variation.

I checked the every single line of the c++ codes in my files. Its exactly same in both cases. But only the computation time has been decreased more than 30 times. I have no idea what's happening. Can anyone help me?

*Note:* 
 *Both the computer have exactly the same configuration.* 
 *Also, the function has been called same 'n' number of times in both the cases*

```
Intensity getIntensity (Grids &inputGrids, Mat inputImage)// groups of 2d grids
{
    type allGridIntensity;
    for()//takes single grid
    {
        type singleGridIntensity;
        for()//takes single point
        {
            double intensity = inputImage.at<uchar>(yPose, xPose);
            singleGridIntensity.push_back(intensity);
        }
        allGridIntensity.push_back(singleGridIntensity);
    }
    return allGridIntensity;
}
```

Comment: Any code? It's hard to estimate if there's no code fragment.

Comment: Are you running a Release build on the Windows machine or a Debug build?

Comment: I am running in release mode..

Comment: Give us the line that runs x40 slower. Or every line runs 40x slower?

Comment: @SidZhang.. The code is very simple a function takes cv::Mat image and float of (x,y) points. for each function call returns a intensity value of the particular position (x,y) in image. I don't think there is a mistake in coding because it runs well in Ubuntu.

Comment: This sounds like a compiler optimization.

Comment: @SidZhang.. I have uploaded the codes here

Comment: @chris_chris Can you also paste the optimization page? Since performance issue is complex. And, is a copy of `Mat` a must? How about `Mat&` or `const Mat&`?

Comment: 1. invalid video decoder codec can slow things down, 2. any HW acceleration (different driver implementation can cause this easily)? 3. similar HW setup on both machines ?

Comment: Did you link ti opencv debug libraries?

Comment: @Micka. Yes, I linked it. But sometimes I cannot use functions like imshow, imread, namedwindow. At that time it shows unhadled exception in opencv_highgui231.dll.

Comment: @Spektre. How to figure it out?

Comment: @SidZhang. What do you mean by optimization page? I already tried Mat& as well as const Mat&. It doesnt helps.

Comment: I guess he means the page that handles the optimization parameters in your Visual Studio project configuration?!?

Comment: @chris_chris minimize the app so it does not do what you need but first just decode video only from stream (rem the rest) and benchmark it on booth machines/OS. if there is big difference then it is your cause if not problem is elsewhere so un rem filter and try again. when you locate the part of code that is 'slow' add more info ... also you wrote you are doing computations on floats make sure your float values (near zero) are normalized (along the computation) else that could cause big slowdowns !!!

Comment: @chris_chris I hope the measurements was done for at least times bigger then 10 ms (many frames per one time measurement) else you do not know what you actually measure ...

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to help without code, but if you run in such a big gap in performance I'd check Optimization setting of your compiler. When you have `for` cycle and your implementation suits to that compiler will parallelize your code and you will run much faster. But it's just a guessing without proper code example